# EJBCA Response Envelope encryption - DES algorithm phase out for iOS devices

Tags: encryption, ios

As per Apple WWDC this year, DES encryption algorithm will be phased out soon.

I noticed that DES is the hard coded encryption algorithm in ScepResponseMessage.java in EJBCA's code.

```
CMSEnvelopedData ed = edGen.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(s.getEncoded()), SMIMECapability.dES_CBC.getId(), "BC");
```

This implies clients (say iOS devices) will have to support DES in order to decrypt the Envelope. Can this encryption algorithm be changed to Triple DES or AES?